# PHPUnit переопределить переменную из файла phpunit.xml

Tags: laravel, phpunit

В файле конфигурации `phpunit.xml` определяется серверная переменная:

```
<php>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
</php>
```

Соответственно, в тестах используется значение `mysql`:

```
echo (env('DB_CONNECTION')); // выводится mysql
```

Я хочу через консоль переопределить это значение, что-то типа

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite phpunit
```

Или, поскольку используется Laravel, то

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite artisan test
```

Оба варианта рабочие, но значения из `phpunit.xml` имеют больший приоритет, поэтому так сделать не получится. Может есть другой какой-либо способ? Из пожеланий - не хотелось бы менять `phpunit.xml` или другие части кода, только какое-то консольное решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для локального тестирования, создайте копию `phpunit.xml.dist`:

```bsh
cp phpunit.xml phpunit.xml.dist
```

Далее определяйте ваше локальное тестовое окружение в `phpunit.xml.dist`, который по умолчанию прописан в `.gitignore` так же как и `.env`

Comment: Тут все наоборот, `phpunit.xml.dist` имеет меньший приоритет, чем без `.dist`. Поменять местами можно, но это не то, что мне хотелось бы - мне нужен консольный путь. Я буду регулярно использовать разные значения - как sqlite, так и mysql, и для этого придется редактировать файл, что не хочется делать.

Comment: В таком случае вам будет удобнее использовать не `env`, а аргументы командной строки (`$argv`) https://stackoverflow.com/a/39662597/10249529